# Model in keras giving error when doing fit

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to make a simple image classification Neural Network with Keras but unable to figure out why the error is coming in model.fit!

My image shape is (300,300,3) and I am converting it to (27000,) for the sake of simplicity (I am beginner in Machine Learning, Correct me if I am wrong somewhere;)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(270000,), activation='relu')) #For image with shape (300,300,3)
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

dataset = []
i = 1
while i <= 3:
    n = 1000
    while n:
        temp_img = plt.imread('finger_dataset/' + str(i) + '/' + str(n) + '.png')
        dataset.append([temp_img, i])
        n -= 1
    i += 1

random.shuffle(dataset)

i = 0
X_train = []
y_train = []
while i < len(dataset):
    X_train.append(dataset[i][0])
    y_train.append(dataset[i][1])
    i+=1

X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

X_train = X_train.reshape((len(X_train), -1))
y_train = y_train.reshape((-1,1))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)
```

The error i am getting after running **model.fit(....)** is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
   1351 

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
   1444 

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 270000
  }
  dim {
    size: 512
  }
}
float_val: 0

     [[{{node training/SGD/moment_0}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fef3f263c0f5> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1211         else:
   1212             fit_inputs = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1213         self._make_train_function()
   1214         fit_function = self.train_function
   1215 

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    331                     updates=updates + metrics_updates,
    332                     name='train_function',
--> 333                     **self._function_kwargs)
    334 
    335     def _make_test_function(self):

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in function(inputs, outputs, updates, **kwargs)
   3004 def function(inputs, outputs, updates=None, **kwargs):
   3005     if _is_tf_1():
-> 3006         v1_variable_initialization()
   3007     return tf_keras_backend.function(inputs, outputs,
   3008                                      updates=updates,

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in v1_variable_initialization()
    418 
    419 def v1_variable_initialization():
--> 420     session = get_session()
    421     with session.graph.as_default():
    422         variables = tf.global_variables()

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in get_session()
    383             '`get_session` is not available when '
    384             'TensorFlow is executing eagerly.')
--> 385     return tf_keras_backend.get_session()
    386 
    387 

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py in get_session(op_input_list)
    484   if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
    485     with session.graph.as_default():
--> 486       _initialize_variables(session)
    487   return session
    488 

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py in _initialize_variables(session)
    908       v._keras_initialized = True
    909     if uninitialized_vars:
--> 910       session.run(variables_module.variables_initializer(uninitialized_vars))
    911 
    912 

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    954     try:
    955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 956                          run_metadata_ptr)
    957       if run_metadata:
    958         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1178     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1179       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1180                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1181     else:
   1182       results = []

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1357     if handle is None:
   1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1359                            run_metadata)
   1360     else:
   1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 270000
  }
  dim {
    size: 512
  }
}
float_val: 0

     [[node training/SGD/moment_0 (defined at c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'training/SGD/moment_0':
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 505, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 422, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1434, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1233, in inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 357, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 267, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 534, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2819, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2845, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3020, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3191, in run_ast_nodes
    if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-fef3f263c0f5>", line 1, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1213, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 202, in get_updates
    for (i, shape) in enumerate(shapes)]
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 202, in <listcomp>
    for (i, shape) in enumerate(shapes)]
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 963, in zeros
    v = tf.zeros(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 2350, in zeros
    output = fill(shape, constant(zero, dtype=dtype), name=name)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 171, in fill
    result = gen_array_ops.fill(dims, value, name=name)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3602, in fill
    "Fill", dims=dims, value=value, name=name)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\aakash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


1
​
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your issue, but `loss='mse'` (i.e. regression problem) with `metrics=['accuracy']` (i.e. classification problem) does not make any sense. The same holds true for a single-node final layer with `activation='relu'`.

Comment: @desertnaut can you explain me some more! What are the points I am missing here! I am new to ML

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tensorflow==2.0 or 2.2 
try

```
loss_fn=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO, name='mean_squared_error')
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

well it worked for me... try it... 
And i am new too so peace

Comment: I think the loss is not correct for image classification. MSE makes sense for regression. I suggest change the loss to crossentropy